# Transform XML with missing namespace

Tags: xml, xslt, soap, xslt-1.0

When I'm make a call to a webservice function, I get this response xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope>
  <soap:Body>
    <Response>
      <Result>
        <Status>Success</Status>
        <Text>Some text</Text>
      </Result>
     </Response>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

As you can see, the response xml does not include the soap namespace.

I want to transform the xml by removing the soap-stuff, and while I was making the xsl transformation I got this to work by adding the soap namespace to the response xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Response>
      <Result>
        <Status>Success</Status>
        <Text>Some text</Text>
      </Result>
     </Response>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How can I do this transformation when the soap namespace is not included in the response xml?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That is what I would call malformed XML. No matter what you try to transform it with, any sensible XSLT parser is going to give some variant of an "Unbound Prefix" error. Because the source document is "confused" about its namespace usage, any subsequent XSLT is going to be confused, as well.

From [`Namespaces in XML 1.1`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names11/#ns-qualnames):

> **Namespace constraint: Prefix Declared**
>
> **The namespace prefix, unless it is xml or xmlns, must have been
>   declared in a namespace declaration attribute in either the start-tag
>   of the element where the prefix is used or in an ancestor element
>   (i.e. an element in whose content the prefixed markup occurs).**
>   Furthermore, the attribute value in the innermost such declaration
>   must not be an empty string.

I'm afraid you're going to have to contact whoever publishes this web service and get them to change their response format to be proper XML.

Answer (score 1):

That input is well-formed but not namespace-well-formed XML.  You may be able to parse it into a DOM tree using a parser that is configured to be non-namespace-aware and then use XSLT constructs like

```
<xsl:template match="*[local-name() = 'soap:Envelope']">
```

but whether that is possible and if so exactly how you would do it depends on what XSLT processor you're using, I can't give a more detailed answer without knowing that.